# Can AWS Fargate be used without a load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-fargate

Initially I expect traffic to my web application to be minimal and I do not want to bear the cost of a load balancer. But if my application gains traction then I may configure a load balancer later. Is it possible to use AWS Fargate without a load balancer?

Comment: Fargate tasks in public subnets are assigned public and private IP both. You can access your task using public IP .

Comment: They're less than 3 cents per hour.

Answer (score 5):

That's not easily achievable, see this thread - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=931880

The simplest approach is to assign a load balancer. If you really don't want to do that they suggest running some script that will update the DNS every time a task is deployed.

I believe you should go with a LB as long as there's no traction the cost is negligible.

Comment: If I were to use a Network Load Balancer will it need to run continuously irrespective of the volume of traffic or does it run only when an HTTP request is received from the  client application?

Comment: Yes, I believe it has to run continuously. Here are some tips for reducing cost (basically use ALB and not ELB) - https://medium.com/cognitoiq/how-cognitoiq-are-using-application-load-balancers-to-cut-elastic-load-balancing-cost-by-90-78d4e980624b

Comment: This is insane, LOL

Comment: "the cost is negligible" try running many environments each replicating many non-http services.

Comment: Downvoting for "negligible cost" - ALBs are extremely expensive once you have more than 1

Answer (score 5):

Not purely on AWS if you want https. With HTTP it is possible using the ECS Service Discovery. You could technically combine CloudFlare with ECS/Service Discovery for HTTP and configure your security groups to block all traffic except CloudFlare (they publish an IP list), and this will allow your public site to be secure while avoiding the need to use an ELB on AWS.

Comment: Or you could use AppRunner